# How to dynamically disable cloudzoom depending on image width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using [cloudzoom](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom) and I have the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="main-image" class="cloudzoom" src="/img/image1.jpg" data-cloudzoom="variableMagnification: false, zoomOffsetX: 0, zoomPosition: 'inside', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image1.jpg" />
  <div id="thumbnail-images">
    <img class='cloudzoom-gallery' src="/img/image2.jpg" data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image: '/img/image2.jpg', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image2.jpg'">
    <img class='cloudzoom-gallery' src="/img/image3.jpg" data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image: '/img/image3.jpg', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image3.jpg'">
  </div>
</div>
```

I use this code to initialize cloudzoom:

```
$('#container', context).once('initiateCloudzoom').each(function () {
    CloudZoom.quickStart();
});
```

This implementation is working fine, but my question is:

How do I disable cloudzoom if my main image is less than X pixels wide?

Also if when I click one of the thumbnails how do I disable or enable cloudzoom depending on the same condition (image width) once the image has been swapped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `X`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError 700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give disableZoom value to auto. It will disable only if zoom image is the same size or smaller than small image. Note, if you have set magnification levels larger than 1, zoom will not be disabled.

```
 <div id="container">
  <img id="main-image" class="cloudzoom" src="/img/image1.jpg" data-cloudzoom="variableMagnification: false, zoomOffsetX: 0, zoomPosition: 'inside', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image1.jpg'" />
  <div id="thumbnail-images">
    <img class='cloudzoom-gallery' src="/img/image2.jpg" data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image: '/img/image2.jpg', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image2.jpg', disableZoom:'auto'">
    <img class='cloudzoom-gallery' src="/img/image3.jpg" data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image: '/img/image3.jpg', zoomImage: '/img-zoom/image3.jpg', disableZoom:'auto'">
  </div>
</div>
```